# В чем лучше хранить данные Cordova-приложения, чтобы не потерять при переносе

Tags: android, cordova

Добрый день! Я разрабатываю небольшую мобильную Android-игру на Cordova и пока храню данные в LocalStorage. Первая версия игры уже в магазине, и пользователи жалуются на лаги, особенно на старых устройствах.

Для улучшения производительности я хочу использовать в следующей версии плагин Crosswalk, но столкнулся с тем, что в этом случае все данные из LocalStorage удаляются (это отдельные браузер, поэтому логика работы понятна).

Вопрос в следующем, на какую технологию хранения данных лучше перейти - Web SQL или SQLite, - чтобы пользователи не потеряли данные при обновлении игры, но с другой стороны движок БД не сильно грузил систему. Может быть, есть еще какие-то альтернативные варианты?